# How to get all month names and need to show month data

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Pnum    Fdate           description
====    ==========      ===========
1024    2018-02-17      A
1024    2018-05-17      B
1024    2018-05-17      C
1024    2018-09-17      D
```

MY table PW have fields looks like this.
--> I want to show the result as

```
**Month Name    Description**
January       -
February      A
March         -
April         -
May           B
June          -
July          -
August        C
September     D
October       -
November      -
December      -
```

Please help me how to achive this.

Comment: It is rather unclear how "C" moves from May to August.  Please explain the logic.

Comment: So, how would you go about getting the month from the Fdate value? Perhaps there is a function that exists for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join with a list of month names, there is only twelve of them:

```
SELECT monthname, description
FROM (VALUES
    (1, 'January'),
    (2, 'February'),
    (3, 'March'),
    (4, 'April'),
    (5, 'May'),
    (6, 'June'),
    (7, 'July'),
    (8, 'August'),
    (9, 'September'),
    (10, 'October'),
    (11, 'November'),
    (12, 'December')
) AS va(monthnumber, monthname)
LEFT JOIN yourdata ON DATEPART(MONTH, fdate) = va.monthnumber
ORDER BY monthnumber
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=6886ee1fb23d867e1ae65633aaeb61d5)**

```
with cte1 as (
      select cast('2018-01-01' as date) dt
      union all
      select dateadd(month, 1, dt)
      from cte1 
      where dateadd(month, 1, dt) < cast('2018-12-31' as date)
     )

select DateName(month,dt),coalesce(Description,'-') as Description from cte1 a left join yourtable b 
on month(a.dt)=month(b.Fdate)
```

Comment: I don’t think the dt in dateadd(month, 1, dt) will work. AFAIK aliases aren’t valid function input.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll - you can check https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=485dbfecf3c72628785dc313172bbd83

Comment: @BrianDriscoll It works fine, did you try it? The alias there is fed by a recursive CTE.

Comment: Tq for u r rply, but what is times object ,my system showing times is a  invalid Object.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(fdate), description FROM table
```

For more reference go through
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
;WITH CTE(Pnum,  Fdate,description)
AS
(
SELect 1024,'2018-02-17','A' union all
SELect 1024,'2018-05-17','B' union all
SELect 1024,'2018-08-17','C' union all
SELect 1024,'2018-09-17','D' 
)
SELECT MonthNames,ISNULL([Description],'-') AS [Description]
FROM CTE RIGHT JOIN
(
    SELECT DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH,number-datepart(month,GETDATE()),GETDATE())) as MonthNames
    FROM MASTER.DBO.spt_values
    WHERE TYPE ='P'
     AND number BETWEEN 1 AND 12
 ) dt 
ON dt.MonthNames=DATENAME(MONTH,Fdate)
```

Result

```
MonthNames  Description
--------------------------
January     -
February    A
March       -
April       -
May         B
June        -
July        -
August      C
September   D
October     -
November    -
December    -
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution will allow an index on `Fdate` to be used (`MONTH(column)` will force a scan every time).

```
DECLARE @year int = 2018;

;WITH m AS
(
  SELECT m = 1 UNION ALL SELECT m + 1 FROM m WHERE m < 12
),
months(b,e) AS
(
  SELECT b = DATEFROMPARTS(@year, m,   1)
  FROM m
)
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, m.b), PW.Description
FROM months AS m
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.PW 
ON PW.Fdate >= m.b AND PW.Fdate < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, m.b)
ORDER BY m.b;
```